# Эксцесса не равна нулю при расчёте с помощи функции kurtosis

Tags: python, python-3.x, статистика, теория-вероятностей

Было построено нормальное распределение через `norm.pdf()`. Эксцесса рассчитывалась (для полученного нормального распределения) при помощи функции `kurtosis()` (импортирована из `scipy.stats`).

Для любого нормального распределения эксцесса - ноль, однако здесь получается `e>3`.

Что не так?

Код на [PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/MAmihCKX)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import kurtosis, norm

# Значения между -10 и 10 с шагом 0.0001
x_axis = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.0001)
# Среднее значение = 0, стандартное отклонение = 2.
plt.plot(x_axis, norm.pdf(x_axis, scale=1))
plt.show()
e = kurtosis(norm.pdf(x_axis, scale=1))
print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы считаете `kurtosis` от **результата применения функции плотности нормального распределения**.

Вот примеры:

```
In [195]: kurtosis(np.random.normal(0, 2, 10**6))
Out[195]: -0.0016844623062004516

In [196]: kurtosis(np.random.normal(4, 100, 10**6))
Out[196]: 0.009394822923562529
```